# Two columns but not for entire document

Tags: two-column

My goal is for my document to have a standard article documentclass to use the pages for an essay setting, but at the end I need to include newspaper articles and would like to format the latter pages as two columns for these newspaper articles. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I should approach this? Tables are not reasonable for obvious reasons and I am not sure what other tools are at my disposal.

So generally I would like to format my document as

> Essay Body
>
> References
>
> (Two Column Start)
>
> Articles
>
> (Two Column End)

**Edit:**

Can I force all of the remainder into the left column only instead of having it balance? Also can I increase the space between the columns slightly?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried inserting the instruction `\twocolumn` at the start of appendix (at least I assume it's some kind of appendix) that shows the articles? A new page will start automatically when the `\twocolumn` instruction is encountered. The material on the final page of the two-column part of the document will not be balanced -- this is what you want, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `multicol` package. Add `\usepackage{multicol}` to your document preamble, and wrap the text you want in columns in `\begin{multicols}{n}` and `\end{multicols}` where `n` is the number of columns. For more information, see the [package documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/multicol.pdf).

However, you cannot use floats that span just one column; `multicol` can only handle the starred float environments, which span both columns.

The `multicol` package automatically balances the columns; if you don't want this, use the `multicols*` envoironment.

Comment: Is there no environment that will throw the remainder into the left column on the last page?

Comment: To change the separation between columns one can set `\columnsep`, as in `\setlength\columnsep{30pt}`.